# Share common functions between components in react native

Tags: react-native

I am developping a react native chart library named [react-native-chart-wrapper](https://github.com/wuxudong/react-native-charts-wrapper) which contains BarChart, LineChart, ... etc.

I want to expose several functions to js(e.g., moveViewToX)

In android, both BarChartManager and LineChartManager inherit BarLineChartBaseManager, so it is ok to put getCommandsMap and receiveCommand in BarLineChartBaseManager.

BarLineChartBaseManager

```
protected static final int MOVE_VIEW_TO = 1;

@Nullable
@Override
public Map<String, Integer> getCommandsMap() {
    return MapBuilder.of("moveViewToX", MOVE_VIEW_TO_X);    
}

@Override
public void receiveCommand(T root, int commandId, @Nullable ReadableArray args) {
    switch (commandId) {
        case MOVE_VIEW_TO_X:
            root.moveViewToX((float) args.getDouble(0));
            return;
    }

    super.receiveCommand(root, commandId, args);
}
```

But how to do it in js part?

Currently, js code is list below, simple and clear.

BarChart

```
const iface = {
  name: 'BarChart',
  propTypes: {
    ...BarLineChartBase.propTypes,

    drawValueAboveBar: PropTypes.bool,
    drawBarShadow: PropTypes.bool,

    data:  barData
  }
};

export default requireNativeComponent('RNBarChart', iface, {
  nativeOnly: { onSelect: true }
});
```

LineChart

```
const iface = {
  name: 'LineChart',
  propTypes: {
    ...BarLineChartBase.propTypes,

    data: lineData,
  }
};

export default requireNativeComponent('RNLineChart', iface, {
  nativeOnly: { onSelect: true }
});
```

I don't want to repeat below js code in every chart definition, and inheritance is not suggested in react. What should I do?

```
moveViewToX(x) {
  UIManager.dispatchViewManagerCommand(
      React.findNodeHandle(this),
      UIManager.RNBarChart.Commands.moveViewToX,
      [x],
  );
}
```

**UPDATE**

I tried the high-order-composition.

Movable

```
export default function Movable(WrappedComponent) {
  return class MovableExtended extends React.Component {
    move() {
      console.log('I extended the wrapped component with functionality move')
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent move={this.move}/>
    }
  }
}
```

Highlightable

```
export default function Highlightable(WrappedComponent) {
  return class HighlightableExtended extends React.Component {
    highlight() {
      console.log('I extended the wrapped component with functionality highlight')
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent highlight={this.highlight}/>
    }
  }
}
```

BarLineChart

```
export default HighlightableChart(MovableChart(BarLineChart))
```

App

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <BarLineChart ref="chart"/>
    );
  }
}
```

`this.refs.chart.highlight()` function is working. 
and 
`Uncaught TypeError: this.refs.chart.move is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Final Solution**

This is the simplest pattern I have found. Easy to extend.

```
class LineChart extends React.Component {
  getNativeComponentName() {
    return 'RNLineChart'
  }

  getNativeComponentRef() {
    return this.nativeComponentRef
  }

  render() {
    return <RNLineChart {...this.props} ref={ref => this.nativeComponentRef = ref} />;
  }
}

LineChart.propTypes = {
  ...BarLineChartBase.propTypes,

  data: lineData,
};

var RNLineChart = requireNativeComponent('RNLineChart', LineChart, {
  nativeOnly: {onSelect: true}
});

export default MoveEnhancer(LineChart);




class BarChart extends React.Component {
  getNativeComponentName() {
    return 'RNBarChart'
  }

  getNativeComponentRef() {
    return this.nativeComponentRef
  }

  render() {
    return <RNBarChart {...this.props} ref={ref => this.nativeComponentRef = ref} />;
  }
}

BarChart.propTypes = {
  ...BarLineChartBase.propTypes,

  drawValueAboveBar: PropTypes.bool,
  drawBarShadow: PropTypes.bool,

  data: barData
}

var RNBarChart = requireNativeComponent('RNBarChart', BarChart, {
  nativeOnly: {onSelect: true}
})

export default MoveEnhancer(BarChart)




export default function MoveEnhancer(Chart) {
  return class MovableExtended extends Chart {
    moveViewToX(x) {
      UIManager.dispatchViewManagerCommand(
        findNodeHandle(this.getNativeComponentRef()),
        UIManager[this.getNativeComponentName()].Commands.moveViewToX,
        [x]
      );
    }
  }
}
```